# Helvetica or Verdana which is better supported on all major browsers

Tags: html, css

Helvetica or Verdana which is better supported on all major browsers both these fonts render differently of IE & FF.

What font is best recommended for all browsers

Comment: I wouldn't just pick 1 font to be used. Within my CSS I usually provide many alternatives in-case a font is not supported...

Comment: It depends which fonts are installed on your computer - I don't think windows machines come with helvetica as you need a license to use it, whereas verdana does come with windows machines.  If you want to make sure your site uses helvitica, you can always use an @font-face but you'll have to pay for the license to include the font in your website

Answer (score 7):

About the OS support, from http://cssfontstack.com/

**Helvetica** 
Mac: 100%
Windows: 7.34%

**Verdana** 
Mac: 99.1%
Windows: 99.84%

Answer (score 1):

Both Helvetic and Verdana are websafe fonts. All major browsers should support them. Although font support more depends on the operating system.

A complete list could be found at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: It shows which font are going well together. If you prefer Helvetica your can just make the family Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif. It is a family definition not a list in order of which is better. It shows that if you want Arial, Helvetica could be a good second choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that Verdana is more widely supported.

If you look here : http://www.3cstudios.com/WebsafeFonts.aspx - Helvetica is listed as a Mac only font whereas Verdana is present on both operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Helvetica as default and define Arial (the windows version) in your CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Helvetica is supported on all browsers and I can't remember any browser not supporting Verdana